# Feeding functions as parameters in Scheme

Tags: function, parameters, scheme, composition, function-call

I am new to Scheme programming and working on an assignment. I have multiple functions with `func3` sitting at the top and `func1` feeding to `func2` which then feeds into `func3`. For example I have something like this

```
(define func1
  (lambda (a b)
    (+ a b)))

(define func2
  (lambda (x y)
    (+ x y)))   ;;; y is a function of above function1
```

I have created `func3` as below

```
(define func3
  (lambda (a b x)
    func2 (x (func1 (a b)))))
```

Is there something that I doing grossly wrong or is it something simple? Let me know if any clarifications are needed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You got the syntax right in both `(+ a b)` and `(+ x y)`, but then you decided to try something else for some reason. (In contrast to other languages, `+` and other mathematical operators are not special in Scheme – they have slightly peculiar names but work like other functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're calling the procedures isn't right, this is how it should look like:

```
(define func3
  (lambda (a b x)
    (func2 x (func1 a b))))
```

As you can see, some of the parentheses in your code were misplaced. The key is to understand how to *call* a procedure, for example this was wrong:

```
func2(x ...)  ; missing `(` at the left
```

This is also incorrect:

```
(func1 (a b)) ; don't surround parameters with `()`
```

The correct way is to surround each procedure call with `()` but not its parameters, *unless they're procedure calls themselves*. Like this:

```
(func1 a b)
(func2 x (func1 a b))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out what I did wrong. That definitely helped